# Jenkins P4 plugin files syncing

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I have a problem with files syncing in Jenkins using P4 plugin. My P4 plugin configuration is:
Workspace behaviour: Manual, Clobber type writable
Populate options: Auto cleanup and sync, checked replace missing/modified files and quiet perforce messages.
So when I build my job and I try to syncing files in my workspace I get this console output:

```
Building in workspace /home/mateusz/Perforce/mczer_jenkins_depot
... p4 client -o mczer_jenkins_depot +
... p4 info +
... p4 info +
... p4 client -o mczer_jenkins_depot +
...   No change in client detected.
... p4 counter change +
... p4 changes -m1 -ssubmitted //mczer_jenkins_depot/... +
... p4 repos -C +
Building on Node: master
... p4 client -o mczer_jenkins_depot +
... p4 info +
... p4 info +
... p4 client -o mczer_jenkins_depot +
...   No change in client detected.

P4 Task: establishing connection.
... server: perforce-wro.dolby.net:1666
... node: mateusz-VirtualBox

P4 Task: reverting all pending and shelved revisions.
... p4 revert /home/mateusz/Perforce/mczer_jenkins_depot/... +
... rm [abandoned files]
duration: (20ms)

P4 Task: cleaning workspace to match have list.
... p4 reconcile -w -f -e -d /home/mateusz/Perforce/mczer_jenkins_depot/... +
duration: (17ms)

P4 Task: syncing files at change: 4999572
... p4 sync -q /home/mateusz/Perforce/mczer_jenkins_depot/...@4999572 -
p4 sync -q /home/mateusz/Perforce/mczer_jenkins_depot/...@4999572

... totalFileSize 29219346999
... totalFileCount 33325

P4 Task: attempt: 1
ERROR: P4: Task Exception: com.perforce.p4java.exception.ConnectionException: Unexpected exception in ClientSystemFileCommands.openFile: nulljava.lang.NullPointerException

Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get this rather unhelpful error when the p4 plugin can't open the to-be-synced file for write.

One possible cause is OS permissions.   For example, you started jenkins as 'root' in the past but now run it as user 'mateusz'.

So check ownership of /home/mateusz/Perforce/mczer_jenkins_depot.   Can the jenkins process user write to it and all dirs/files below?

Comment: Thaks bro, I made a new depot which owner is jenkins user and that works good ! :)